# Fail to loop in creating multiple NCDF4 files from analysis

Tags: r

I have the following script to write analysis outputs to individual NCDF4 files. The script is writing the first file and stops.
the error i am getting is :-

Error in R_nc4_create: Permission denied (creation mode was 4096)
Error in nc_create(ncfname, list(tmp_def, tmp_def2), force_v4 = T) : 
  Error in nc_create!

there appears to be something wrong with the:-

```
ncfname<- sprintf('%sA.nc', Listbreak3)
```

and I can't figure it out.

My script is part of a much larger analysis. But the the part of interests is below.

It could be the loop, But I think the loop is okay

Hope somebody has wrote multiple NCDF4 files

Write NCDF4 files

#

```
  tunits<-"days since 1800-01-01 00:00:00"

  #Define dimensions
  ##################################################################
  londim<-ncdim_def("Lon","degrees_east",as.double(Lon))
  latdim<-ncdim_def("Lat", "degrees_north",as.double(Lat))
  timedim<-ncdim_def("timeset",tunits,as.double(timeset))

  #Define variables
  ##################################################################
  fillvalue<-NA

  dlname<-"2 meter air temperature"
  dlname2<-" 2 meter max air temperature"

  tmp_def<-ncvar_def("Y2ts_Stripped","deg_C",
  list(londim,latdim,timedim),fillvalue,dlname,prec = "double")
  tmp_def2<-ncvar_def("X2ts_Stripped","deg_C", 
  list(londim,latdim,timedim),fillvalue,dlname2,prec = "double")

  ncatt_put(ncout,"Lon","axis","X")
  ncatt_put(ncout, "Lat", "axis", "Y")
  ncatt_put(ncout, "timeset","axis", "T")

  #################################################
  title<-c( 1:2 )
  names(title)<-c("jack","jill")
  title<-as.data.frame(title)
  ###############################################  
   Listbreak<-filelist


   #Create Ncdf4 file and  put arrays 
   ##################################################################
   for (i in 1:length( Listbreak)){
   Listbreak2<-do.call(rbind, strsplit(Listbreak, "[[:punct:]]|\\s")) 
   [,c(1, 2,3)]###Breaking up the file name
   Listbreak3<-Listbreak2[,2]


    ncfname<- sprintf('%sA.nc', Listbreak3)

    ncout<-nc_create(ncfname,list(tmp_def,tmp_def2),force_v4=T) 

    ncvar_put(ncout,tmp_def,Y2ts_Stripped,start=NA,count = NA )

    ncvar_put(ncout,tmp_def2,X2ts_stripped, start= NA,count = NA )

    } 

    # attributes # the 0 designates the attribute as global 
    ###########################################################
    ncatt_put(ncout,0,"Make_NCDF4_File",1, prec="int")
    ncatt_put(ncout,0,"Maynooth_University",1,prec="short")
    ncatt_put(ncout,0,"AR000087828",1, prec="short")
    ncatt_put(ncout,0,"description","this is the script to write NCDF4 
    files")


    #Close file and write date to disk
    ##########################################################
    nc_close(ncout)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unfortunately unable to get your code to work, so if anyone in the future is having issues with creating multiple NetCDF files here is a mock sample code below looping through 3 matrices to output 3 unique .nc files.

Additionally, whenever I get the "4096" error, I find that I didn't execute nc_close and the once the error is thrown I have to restart R.

```
#--- Set up Data 
library(ncdf4)

t1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5) ; 
t2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ; 
t3 <- rev(t2) ;   
time = list(t1,t2,t3)

h1 <- c(-2.1,-2.0,-2.2,-1.99,-2.3) ; 
h2 <- c(-2.1,-2.0,-2.2,-1.9,-2.3,-1.8,-2.4,-1.7,-2.5,-1.6) ; 
h3 <- rev(h2) ;  
height = list(h1,h2,h3)

rm(t1,t2,t3,h1,h2,h3)

#--- Define Dimensions 
dimX <- lapply(time,function(x)ncdim_def( "X", "time", x ))

#--- Define variables
var1d <- lapply(dimX,function(x)ncvar_def("height", "units", x, missval = NaN))

#--- Create the test file
doc_name = list('Case1', 'Case2','Case3')

for (i in 1:length(doc_name)){ 
  ncfname <- paste0(doc_name,'_test.nc') 
  ncout<-nc_create(ncfname[i],var1d[[i]],force_v4=T) 
  ncvar_put(ncout,var1d[[i]],height[[i]])
  nc_close(ncout)
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

error in the loop

Listbreak<-filelist 
  Listbreak2<-do.call(rbind, strsplit(Listbreak, "[[:punct:]]|\s"))[,c(1, 2,3)]###Breaking up the file name
  Listbreak3<-Listbreak2[,2]

N <- length(Listbreak)

for (i in 1:N){

```
ncfname<- paste0(substr(Listbreak[i],1,16),'a.nc')
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use the `nc_create` function, drop the part `force_v4=T`:

```
ncout <- nc_create(ncfname, var1d)
```

and the data itself `var1d` should be a 3-D array.